# Calculating times usingbash variables

Tags: bash, variables, time

I have a time in a variable

time1=14.25

is there any way i can take 30 minutes away from it ? the variable could be any time in 24hour format ?

Comment: what time is 14.25?  14h25m, or 14h15m?

Comment: what does your last question mean? if it is a statement(not a question), what's your definition of `24hour format`? `HH.mm`?

Comment: also, if the variable is `time1=00.01` what result would you expect? if you ask a question, ask clearly please!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming** your format is HH.MM, then with GNU date:

```
$ time1=14.25
$ date -d "$(tr . : <<< "$time1") 30 min ago" +%H.%M
13.55
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a pure BASH way;

You could try `dc`?

```
time2=`echo "$time1 0.30 - p" | dc`
```

or `bc`?

```
time2=`echo "$time1-0.30" | bc`
```

Will that do for you?

Comment: If you're assuming 14.25 is 2PM plus a quarter of an hour, you want to subract 0.5, not 0.3